# Sending a class to the main class from a class

Tags: java, class, object, methods, ioexception

My code is currently set to have 3 class files, main and tradeShip. tradeShip has recieved another class file, playerShip. in the tradeShip code, I need to send playerShip back to main. The code is as follows:

```
public class tradeShip() {
  public void sell(playerShip player) {
    //unimportant code
    main.saveGame(player);
  }
}


public class main() {
  public void saveGame (playerShip player) throws IOException {
    //code that deals with writing to text files
  }
}
```

This however gives me an error at main.saveGame(player); where it says "unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Im not sure exactly whats going on, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: for starters, get rid of the () on your class declarations

Comment: You need to read up on checked exceptions.

Comment: This can't be your actual code... classes don't have parentheses in their declarations. As to your actual problem, your `saveGame` method declares that it can throw an `IOException`. Because this is a checked exception, wherever you call `saveGame` needs to *either* provide a try-catch block to handle the error, or also needs to declare that it throws that same exception in the method signature.

Comment: Also by convention class names start in uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saveGame throws ecxeption (an error)
you have to catch and process it:

```
try {
    main.saveGame(player); // throw exception
} catch (IOException e) {
    //some error processing
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or declare sell throws it too to catch and process it at upper levels

```
 public void sell(playerShip player) throws IOException {
```

Answer (score 0):

In the signature of saveGame method you are throwing an IOException that is not raised in the body of that method. So maybe you have to remove it because you probably are already managing it in any catch clause.

Moreover, just to clarify... All the class name has to be capitalized (this is one of good rule of java programming) and the methods you were talking about don't receive a java class but just an instance of that object type.